# Drupal Image Compression - Distorted Images

Tags: php, drupal, image-processing

I am currently having some image distortinon issues with a Drupal site.  The site uses ImageCache enabled. I have looked through the Image API settings as well as Image Toolkit setttings and they both are set to 100%.  I have even looked into the original image (not in imagecache directory) and it is still being distorted.  Any insight will be greatly appreciated on what may be compressing / distorting these images.

Thanks in advance,

JN

Answer (score 0):

I believe Drupal uses GD for its image manipulation... which is natively supported in most linux distros... as well as PHP, and is best known as G*D D***T.  Your best bet is to install ImageMagick, known as iMagick under PHP.  It is supper simple to use.  Writing a compression function will take you about 6 lines of code at most, and perhaps another 6 if you need to incorporate a switch statement to handle several different formats.

Comment: the problem is ImageMagick and GD are both installed but I do not see what is causing the compression to happen on the site. This is not a site I programmed, I just am just running maintenance on it.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit of this ended up being the settings in CCK.  I went to manage fields for this specific content type and removed the max/min resolution for this content type and it worked.  In addition I verified quality was at 100% in ImageAPI as well as Imagetoolkit.